# How to use multiple conditions in the where clause?

Tags: sql-server

I'm a rookie to SQL Server. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have created two tables called `adding_hanger` and `allot` as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[adding_hanger]
(
    [End_Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Hanger_Location] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [Hanger_Capacity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Hanger_Id]  AS ((CONVERT([varchar](100),substring([Hanger_Location],(1),(3)),0)+'101')+CONVERT([varchar](100),[End_Id],0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Manager_Name] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Manager_Id]  AS ((CONVERT([varchar](4),substring([Social_Security_No],(8),(4)),0)+'31')+CONVERT([varchar](100),[End_Id],0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Manager_Password]  AS ((CONVERT([varchar](3),substring([Manager_Name],(1),(3)),0)+'@')+CONVERT([varchar](3),substring([Hanger_Location],(1),(3)),0)),
    [Social_Security_No] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Date_of_Birth] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Mobile_No] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email_Address] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [House_No] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Address_Line_1] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Address_id]  AS ((CONVERT([varchar](100),substring([City],(1),(3)),0)+'31')+CONVERT([varchar](100),[End_Id],0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [City] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [State] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [Pin_No] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[allot]
(
    [Fromdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [todate] [datetime] NULL,
    [hangarlocation] [char](10) NULL,
    [hangarno] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [planeid] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```

How do I fetch the details of the available hangers that are not allotted within a given range of from and to dates given as input and also not exceeding the capacity of the hanger if allocated already?

Comment: how is hanger capacity calculated ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar. Every column in the adding_hanger will be give as input through web form user interface

Answer (score 1):

First, your spelling of 'hangar' is inconsistent and should be addressed.

I'm assuming that the hangar capacity represents how many allots you can store in that hangar?  If so, the hangar capacity might vary over a given timeframe as allots are added/removed (according to FromDate and ToDate), so your question isn't clear.  If you want a hangar that definitely has a space free over a given period, I would use:

```
declare @from_date datetime, @end_date datetime, @i int

-- Set your start and end dates (replace the dates below with the correct ones)
set @from_date = '2016-07-01'
set @to_date = '2016-07-31'
set @i = 1  -- counter

-- Create a table of dates
select @from_date as date into #dates
while dateadd(day,@i,@from_date) <= @to_date
begin
  insert into #dates values (dateadd(day,@i,@from_date))
end

-- Create table of date, hangar_id, hangar_capacity
select date, hangar_id, hangar_capacity
into #dates_by_hangar
from adding_hangar
inner join #dates on 1 = 1

-- Table showing hangars with at least one free space on every date in the range
select hangar_id from (
  -- 2. Table showing hangar space free on each date
  select a.*, a.hanger_capacity - isnull(b.allots_in_hangar,0) as hangar_space_free
  from #dates_by_hangar a
  left outer join (
    -- 1. Table showing number of allots in each hangar on a given date
    select date, hangar_no, sum(case when b.hangar_no is not null then 1 else 0 end) as allots_in_hangar
    from #dates a
    left outer join allot b
    on a.date between b.fromdate and b.todate
    group by date, hangar_no) b
  on a.hangar_id = b.hangar_no
  and a.date = b.date
)
group by hangar_no
having max(hangar_space_free) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ah.* from [adding_hanger] AS ah 
INNER JOIN [allot] ON allot.hangarlocation = ah.Hanger_Location 
WHERE (allot.Fromdate < <input_from_date> OR allot.todate > <input_to_date>) 
OR (allot.Fromdate >= <input_from_date> AND allot.todate <= <input_to_date> AND ah.Hanger_Capacity <= <input_capacity>)
```